# Reuse objects define in modules

Tags: javascript

I defined a logger with 2 different files and use it like this:

**main.js**

```
var config = require('./config');
var log = require('./services/logger')(config);
log.logger.info("Info Logging");
```

**config.js**

```
var config = {};
var PRODUCTION = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
config.log = {
    level : 'info'
};
module.exports = config;
```

**logger.js**

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    var winston = require('winston');
    var logger = new(winston.Logger)({
            transports : [new(winston.transports.Console)({
                    level : config.log.level
                })]
        });
    var winstonStream = {
        write : function (message, encoding) {
            logger.info(message.slice(0, -1));
        }
    };
    return {
        logger : logger,
        expressStreamLogger : winstonStream
    };
};
```

**Issue**

In another file I want to use the logger (`log.logger`). Should I repeat the following require each time I need to use the logger?

```
var config = require('./config');
var log = require('./services/logger')(config);
log.logger.info("Info Logging");
```

Comment: You could also have the logger import that config as default config and only use it if no other is provided.

Comment: You could use the singleton pattern. Do you actually need to have multiple Logger instances?